# Easiest way to get bigger date unit from specific date Swift

Tags: swift, nsdate

I have 2 example of dates, one is newer then other. I need to output string like "15 minutes before, 10 hours before, 2 day before, 7 week before, 2 year before". So, i need to somehow determine biggest data unit (hour, minute, month, year), and then calculate number of that units.

Is there an easy way to do that without using too much if's and comparing seconds from 2 NSDates?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please try this library :- https://github.com/kevinlawler/NSDate-TimeAgo

Comment: @mitulmarsonia i see that library is for Obj-C. But i look for example for swift.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban If you reed the Read.me of NSDate-TimeAgo, you'll see that it new version is https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools and is in Swift. Also, you should be able to use Objective-C in a Swift Project.

Answer (score 2):

It sound like [`DateComponentsFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter) could be what you are looking for.

I used these two dates as an example

```
let earlier = // 29 Sep 2017, 04:36 
let later   = //  2 Oct 2017, 10:04
```

Creating a components formatter and formatting the components between these two dates (without any further configuration) produces this result:

```
let componentFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
componentFormatter.string(from: earlier, to: later)
// "3d 5:28:07"
```

If, like in your question, you want the formatted string to use the full unit names, you can configure the `unitStyle` of the formatter:

```
componentFormatter.unitsStyle = .full
// "3 days, 5 hours, 28 minutes, 7 seconds"
```

If you want the formatted string to only include the larges unit, you can configure the `maximumUnitCount` of the formatter:

```
componentFormatter.maximumUnitCount = 1
// "3 days"
```

Depending on the accuracy you want to convey to your users, you might want to indicate that this single unit is an approximations. You can do this by enabling `includesApproximationPhrase` on the formatter:

```
componentFormatter.includesApproximationPhrase = true
// "About 3 days"
```